# What JSON Should I be Using For WCF Service

Tags: wcf, json

I am running a WCF service with these methods,

```
public string UploadInspections(Inspection[] inspections)
public string UploadInspection(Inspection inspection)

[DataContract]
public partial class Inspection
{
    [DataMember]
    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int  Id { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public string Comment { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    public int Rating { get; set; }
}
```

From javascript I tried to call a POST on these methods using JSON. The JSON I had for the UploadInspection method was this,

```
{"Id":10,"Comment":"New One","Rating":3}
```

The UploadInspection method was called, but the inspection object was set to null.

I wasn't sure how to specify the Date field using JSON, and I thought that perhaps the parser didn't like JSON with no Date field. I removed the Date field from the Inspection object, but the same thing happened.

Also what should the JSON look like for the UploadInspections method which is an array? I had some JSON that I tried,

```
"inspections": [{"Id":10,"Comment":"New One","Rating":3}]
```

And also this,

```
[{"Id":10,"Comment":"New One","Rating":3}, {"Id":11,"Comment":"New Two","Rating":2}]
```

But I was getting this error,

```
OperationFormatter encountered an invalid Message body. Expected to find an attribute with name 'type' and value 'object'. Found value 'string'.
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem is not what I thought it was, in my service definition it initially looked like this,

```
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest, RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
[OperationContract]
string UploadInspections(Inspection[] inspections);
```

Once I removed this,

```
BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest
```

It worked!

Comment: That is 4 hours of my life and multiple clumps of my hair that I can never get back. Thanks!